# System of Integral equation - Numerical Solving

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, integral-equations

I have those equations:
$$
X_0=\int_a^b K_0(x)f(x) \,dx \\
X_1=\int_a^b K_1(x)f(x) \,dx \\
X_2=\int_a^b K_2(x)f(x) \,dx
$$

$X_0,X_1,X_2$ are from measurement and $K_0,K_1,K_2$ too (numerical value inside $[a,b]$).

That look like those equations could have infinite possibilities. I would like to find some solutions, numerically which respect the constraint:
$$
\forall \ a\le x\le b,\  f(x)\ge0\
$$

Or at least find a method to generate valid solution from where I can do a manual selection.

I want to find $f(x)\ \forall\ a\le x\le b$.

$K_i$ are continious and surjective but could be $=0$.

And $X_i \ge 0$

Thanks

Comment: Are $K_0,K_1,K_2$ _continuous_ or _discrete_ measurements? If $K_i\neq 0$, there are probably an infinity of solutions: just select a small segment where $K_i\neq 0$ and multiply it get $X_i$. If $K_i>0$ on some open set of $(a,b)$ and is continuous, you can easily match your conditions: just select a "small" set, integrate it, and multiply by $f$ such that the product equals $X_i$.

Comment: $K_0,K_1,K_2$ are continuous and finite, but could be $=0$.
And $K_0,K_1,K_2$ are not bijective (just surjective)

Comment: If they are identically zero (zero everywhere), obviously there is no solution if $X_i\neq 0$ and an infinity otherwise.

Comment: $K_i(x)$ could be $=0$ for some specific values of $x$.
I think I didn't explain correctly.
I try to find $f(x)$ for $a\le x\le b$ not the $X_i$.

Comment: So for example your problem could be: Find $f$ such that $3=\int_a^b \sin(x) f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $2=\int_a^b x^2f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $-5=\int_a^b 2*f(x)\,\mathrm{d}(x)$?

Comment: Yes but $K_i(x)$ always varying with x.

Comment: Additional information $X_i \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very ill-conditioned even in term of numerical solutions (it has the numerical tag). We are trying to reconstruct $\vec{f} = [f_0, f_1, ..., f_n]$ given on the grid of points $\vec{x} = [x_0, x_1, ..., x_n]$, $a \leq x_0 < x_n \leq b$. The numerical integration schemes will provide vectors $\vec{W_i} = [w_0, w_1, ..., w_n]$, which are integration weights for $X_i$ and the numerical integral can be calculated from $X_i = \vec{W_i} \cdot \vec{f}$. Unless your function is evaluated on three points, it will generate any number of solutions. In particular, assume that $f(x) = \sum a_i \delta(x_i) $, then $a_i = X_i / K_i(x_i)$ is a solution, as long as all the $x_i$ are different and $a \leq x_i \leq b$ for all $x_i$.

A much better solution would be to assume some form of function for $f(x)$, say a polynomial, and then fit it to solve your integral equations. Given that your data is from measurements, it should also have noise which would cause trouble in finding $f(x)$ without a fitting procedure.

EDIT : corrected subscript appearing on $\delta(x_i)$, it is a Dirac delta function, so that $\int K(x) \delta(x_i) = K(x_i)$. There are a number of comments on the fact that your system has an infinite amount of solutions. In the numerical case, you can find at most three values of $f(x)$ since you have 3 constraints.

If you can assume some form for $f(x)$ with $N$ parameters and $N \leq 3$, you can use standard regression techniques to fit the parameters for your values.

Comment: Hello,
I need more clarification, I didn't understand your solution.
May be my notation are confusing. I rewrite the problem:
$$
A=\int_a^b K_a(x)f(x) dx \\
B=\int_a^b K_b(x)f(x) dx \\
C=\int_a^b K_c(x)f(x) dx
$$

$A,B,C$ is a triplet of scalars. $K_a,K_b,K_c$ are list of scalars. And knowing that I would like to find $f(x)$. We can see the $K$ like continuous values because for the integration I have a smooth expression of $K$ (continuous, noiseless etc).
But its 3 equations.

$\delta_i$ is a Kronecker Symbol?

If I have an idea of the form of $f(x)$ how that help us?